# Gradle - commandLine in a for each

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have the following code but only the last item from `configFilesPath` is being called in the `commandLine` line.

Any ideas what I should be using - so that it runs commandLine for each of the items in `configFilesPath`?

```
@TaskAction
fun create() {
    project.exec({
        workingDir(project.projectDir)

        var configFilesPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "../../../", "myconfig/");
        //Create symlinks for all files in myconfig/
        Files.list(configFilesPath).forEach{
            val configFile = configFilesPath.toString() + "/" + it.fileName
            commandLine("ln", "-s", configFile)
        }
    })

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ExecSpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/process/ExecSpec.html) : when you write `commandLine("ln", "-s", configFile)` you are actually calling the `commandLine` property [setter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/process/ExecSpec.html#commandLine-java.lang.Object...-); if you wrap this call in a `forEach` loop, only the last value will be used (this is what you observed). In fact the `Exec` task can have only one `commandLine`.

In your case you could wrap the `project.exec( {...})` call into the `forEach` block, in order to trigger one `exec` call for each of your config file.

Something like that should work ( code not tested, you might have to adapt a little bit):

```
@TaskAction
fun create() {

    var configFilesPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "../../../", "myconfig/");
    // Iterate over all files in myconfig/
    Files.list(configFilesPath).forEach{
        val configFile = configFilesPath.toString() + "/" + it.fileName
        project.exec({
            workingDir(project.projectDir)
            commandLine("ln", "-s", configFile)
        })
    }
}
```

**Note** you should also configure your task in a `doLast { }` block.